# React - highly rely on url params to determine what to show on the page, is it reliable?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I just started to learn React.js so this question might be silly.

When I just started learning React, I tried to trigger functions based on user interaction with the elements on the page. And those functions heavily rely on state changes. So I implemented `useContext` hook. Basically, I managed to build a web app with 3 nav links, when each link is clicked, a corresponding page shows up without implementing `react-router-dom`... (so the URL doesn't change) hence, heavily relying on state changes to toggle different pages.

Then I learned the React Router. This instantly made `useContext` redundant in my earlier props-passing-toggling-page structure. I figured, maybe naively, wow, if I can `useParams` hook to determine what to show on the page by relying on the parameters passed in children triggered by the `NavLink`/`Link` components, why do I use so many `useState` hooks to toggle between pages?

This is too good to be true!! Isn't it?? Is it a common practice? Is it reliable in terms of safety?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useParams`-This hook gives us access to the params of that particular route. Params are parameters whose values are set dynamically in a URL. In practice URL parameters or query params should be limited to only the essential values like `ID, Namespace and etc.` This is not to confuse with `useState` hook. They solve different problems. Here is for the [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)